# How can i use flex bison code with c++ interface

Tags: c++, parsing, interface, bison

I have declared a function f() in a.h file,defined it in a bison file a.y and called it in 
a.cpp file.

I compile it as:

```
      g++ a.cpp a.tab.c lex.yy.c -o a
```

It is working properly.

Now i want to call this function f() in  b.cpp file.

How can i do this.

Which files are to be included in b.cpp file and which files to be provided at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `#include "a.h"` and call `f()`.

Where does `a.cpp` come from? Generally speaking, using the same prefix for a bison file and another program file is confusing. It appears that `a.cpp` includes a `main()` function (although that's just a guess based on your `g++` invocation), so it's not useful as an object file for some other program. What I'd do is something like the following:

```
bison -d -o parser.c parser.y
# For flex 2.5.4, you cannot put a space between -o and the filename.
# You should seriously think about upgrading to a non-prehistoric version
# flex -o lexer.c lexer.l
flex -olexer.c lexer.l
g++ -c -o parser.o parser.c
g++ -c -o lexer.o lexer.c
g++ -o a a.cpp parser.o lexer.o
g++ -o b b.cpp parser.o lexer.o
```

(The above will change the name of `a.tab.h`, so you'll need to fix that in lexer.l. But it's just a suggestion.)

Comment: Yes,u guessed it right. a.cpp is having a main(). And i have already included a.h in b.cpp but it is not working. The question is how it will go to a.y file. Should i include parser.o and lexer.o while compiling b.cpp

Comment: Please be more specific about what "not working" means. And yes, you need to include parser.o and lexer.o. The header file (a.h) only tells the compiler what the functions' prototypes are. It doesn't tell the compiler where to find the compiled functions, and it certainly has no impact on the linker. So when you produce the final executable, be it a or b, you need to link with parser.o and lexer.o (assuming that `b` requires parsing and lexing, of course.)

Comment: okay..But now problem is i have defined flex & bison files with same name i.e. a.y & a.l, so there can be only one a.c

Comment: And when i changed the name of lex file as lex.l, and giving the command as        flex -o lex.c lex.l   its showing error that it cant open lex.c

Comment: i am not able to generate lexer.c

Comment: @user2114865: what version of flex are you using?

Comment: flex version is 2.5.4

Comment: That should be fine. What error does it give you when you specify -o lexer.c? Please be precise and include the exact command line you used.

Comment: i have given the command          flex -o lexer.c lexer.o       and the error is :- flex : can't open lexer.c

Comment: @user2114865: Sorry. With flex 2.5.4, you can't put a space between -o and the filename. It has to be `flex -olexer.c lexer.o`

Comment: You are ryt...but its still a crap..i have provided lexer.o and parser.o while compiling b.cpp and its showing the error that f() is not declared with this scope..but i have already included a.h

Comment: If you declared `f()` in `a.h` and `#include "a.h"` in `b.cpp`, then you shouldn't get a compiler error. Make sure `a.h` is included before any use of `f`, including using `f` in other header files. Remember that there is *absolutely no relationship* between header files and object files. Including a header file doesn't let the linker know where to find the compiled code, and linking compiled code doesn't give the compiler any information about the function.